# Limitation for semantic drop-down multiple selection

Tags: javascript, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am trying to have a Semantic UI dropdown menu which allows additions but I don't want user to have more than 4 selection.

When user added 4 items to his selection, 4 labels will be added, now he shouldn't be able to add more labels to his selection.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select2.js for the multiple select drop down with limitation.

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

For more appropriate solution please share your code here.